# Sync Wi-Fi Passwords on OS X with Android Phone?

Tags: macos, wifi, android

I have a MacBook Air, and an Android phone (errr phablet!). I go out a lot with both, and every time I go to a new venue, I need to put the Wi-Fi password into both.

Do you know of an application so that, when I add the Wi-Fi password to one of them, I can sync it to the other?

Comment: From looking around, it appears that wifi passwords saved to your Google account on Android can't be displayed without rooting the device, can't be synced to any desktop (Windows or Mac), and can't be moved to a new phone except at the initial phone setup process. Regrading the last one: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26193/can-i-manually-download-my-wifi-settings-to-my-android-device-from-my-google-acc

Answer (score 1):

The Android OS doesn't allow apps to modify the wifi settings, [unless you have a rooted device](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nevercertain.wifipasswords.pro). The alternative you have is to use something like [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) or [Lastpass](https://lastpass.com) which allow notes to sync across devices. You can write your long wifi passwords on the desktop, then open the synced file on your mobile phone and copy&paste it into the form. At least that's what I've been doing all this time.